# SpringBoot, max number of active SseEmitters?

Tags: java, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I am running into a problem with a SpringBoot 2.5 app (problem occurs in earlier versions also.)  Basically, I can (very consistently) only invoke the endpoint below 10 times before all the REST endpoints stop responding.

In my original code I had more code before to track the emitters, etc. but I have simplified it to this to verify the minimal amount of code that still demonstrates the problem.  It makes no sense but it seems like the app can handle no more than 10 SseEmitters at once.  This is a system from sending notifications from the server to the browser so the SseEmitters need to be long-lived.

I have tried this with both Tomcat and Jetty with the same results.  Any insight is appreciated.

```
    @GetMapping("/notification/register/{clientId}")
    public SseEmitter register(@ModelAttribute User user, @PathVariable("clientId") String clientId) {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(MINUTES.toMillis(10));
        return emitter;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that this was an issue with DB connections not being released back to the pool.

I use a @ControllerAdvice and @ModelAttribute to make my custom user object available to the controller methods.  My implementation delivers our custom user object since otherwise only a basic Spring user object is available.

It seems that the associated connection was being held for as long as the SseEmitter was active.

The solution was to disable open-in-view:
`spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`

This was extremely difficult to debug- Spring's behavior in this case is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the maximum amount of connections from your internal Server, tho Tomcat should support up to 200 as a default.
Adding this to your `application.properties` should increase the maximum amount:

`server.tomcat.max-threads=400`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and also set some others but the result is the same.  Still, it does seem I am hitting some thread or socket starvation issue.  Is there an async thread pool in play?

`server.tomcat.accept-count=100`
`server.tomcat.max-connections=10000`
`server.tomcat.max-threads=400`
`server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=20`